# How to make div in bootstrap grid scrollable while keeping page non-scrolling

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, scroll, flexbox

I'm building a web app using Bootstrap 4.  The page itself should never scroll.  The child panels should scroll if their content is too large.

This is what I want:
[image]
but this demo is using jQuery and I don't want to use jQuery at all in the project.  I would like to do this with CSS (flexbox?)

If I comment out the jQuery, the div extends below the app area and causes the page to scroll, which I don't want:
[image]

I tried adding this to the red div:

```
max-height: calc(100% - 20px);
overflow-y: auto;
```

But the percentage doesn't work.  Something like `max-height: calc(210px - 20px);` does work, but when you resize the window, it's broken.

Is there a simple (or complex, if necessary) way to accomplish this with CSS?

https://codepen.io/jimjb/pen/wvowZOa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @return_false for getting me on the right path.  @return_false's answer didn't have Bootstrap which was in the title and first sentence of the post.  I want to show an answer that has the bare minimum in the css (which using Bootstrap classes helps with).  As demonstrated in the original Codepen, I also wanted the notes div to scroll but the label to *not* scroll (I can see that may not have been apparent from my description *if* you don't refer to the Codepen).

I think the main takeaway for me was that it is important that each container have a height, including the main container; that seemed to be the key.

```css
.main_container {
  height: 100vh; /* 100% viewport height */
  overflow: hidden; /* hide overflow to prevent scrolling */
}

.notes_scroll {
  height: calc(100% - 25px); /* subtract the 'Notes' label height */
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div{
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}

.problem-div{
  background-color: #FBB;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="grid">
  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-sm-4">left</div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="row h-50">
          top
        </div>
        <div class="row h-50">
          
          <div class="col-sm-6 h-100">
            <div class="row">
              Notes
            </div>
            <div class="row problem-div notes_scroll">
              Many notes 1<br>Many notes 2<br>
              Many notes 3<br>Many notes 4<br>
              Many notes 5<br>Many notes 6<br>
              Many notes 7<br>Many notes 8
            </div>
          </div> 
          <div class="col-sm-6">bottom right</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</section>
```

https://codepen.io/jimjb/pen/XWNWPbX

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need `overflow:scroll` and also one of the ancestor elements needs to have a height for the max-height to work. Here is a coded example:

```css
.main_container {
  width: 100%;
  /* height is 100% viewport height */
  height: 100vh;
  /* Hide overflow here to prevent scrolling */
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  background:#efefef;
}


/* set the container to scroll */

.notes_scroll {
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  padding: 25px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}


/* hide scrollbar */

.notes_scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.sec {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  max-width: 30%;
  background: #dadada;
}

.right {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.top {
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.notes {
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.bottom_right {
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="sec left">Left</div>
  <div class="sec right">
    <div class="sec top">Top</div>
    <div class="sec notes">
      <div class="notes_scroll">
        <h2>Notes</h2>
        <div class="notes_content">
          Many notes...<br/> Many notes...<br/> Many notes...<br/> Many notes...<br/> Many notes...<br/> Many notes...<br/> Many notes...<br/> Many notes...<br/> Many notes...<br/> Many notes...<br/> Many notes...<br/> Many notes...<br/> Many notes...<br/>          Many notes...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sec bottom_right">Bottom Right</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that pretty cool!  I'm not sure how to work it in with the Bootstrap classes that are already there, what styles would be unnecessary with Bootstrap grid system, etc.  I'm guessing there's significant overlap between the css you have and the Bootstrap classes.

Comment: That part you already have done, I just wrote it out to make a complete example. All you need is the commented parts of the code. Just make sure your main container has a height value, then use the scroll code on your existing notes section.